# Extract suffix from url (regex)

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to extract the suffixes from url, meaning:

http://google.com/sports/golf  => sports/golf
http://yahoo.com/blog?id=7     => blog/id=7

How can I acheive that with regex (ruby style)?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need regexp for this. Ruby has a `uri` library in stdlib that works perfectly for this. Check out `URI.parse()` http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: Your question in unclear. Under what rule does `?` change into `/`? Do you always want one slash in the result? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module with `.path + .query`.

```
uri = URI("http://google.com/sports/golf")
uri.path + "/" + uri.query
```

Comment: Adding to this, URI will also strip out any URI fragments ie `sports/golf/?a=b#foo` foo will be stripped but stored in `uri.fragment` if you need that too

Answer (score 1):

How is the below: :)

```
require 'uri'
p URI.split("http://google.com/sports/golf").compact.drop(2).join("/")
p URI.split("http://yahoo.com/blog?id=7").compact.drop(2).join("/")
```

Or,

```
require 'uri'

a = ["http://google.com/sports/golf","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766337/extract-suffix-from-url-regex/15766456#15766456","http://yahoo.com/blog?id=7"]
a.each { |url| p URI.split(url).compact.drop(2).join("/") }
```

output:

```
"/sports/golf"
"/questions/15766337/extract-suffix-from-url-regex/15766456/15766456"
"/blog/id=7"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
irb(main):011:0> /(?:http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/)(.+)/.match("http://yahoo.com/blog?id=7")[1]
=> "blog?id=7"
irb(main):012:0> /(?:http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/)(.+)/.match("http://google.com/sports/golf")[1]
=> "sports/golf"
irb(main):013:0>
```